# EAS Expo Build issue with Installing Dependencies?

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, react-native-native-module

I am trying to use EAS in my managed expo app but running into this issue at the build cmd(`eas build`).

My app works perfectly fine when doing `expo start`.

This is the error log I get from `eas build`. What should I do to fix this problem? I don't understand why it's bascially saying that it can't find my npm folder(at least that appears to be the problem.)

```
Running npm in the root dir of your repository 
[stderr] npm
[stderr] WARN read-shrinkwrap This version of npm is compatible with lockfileVersion@1, but package-lock.json was generated for lockfileVersion@2. I'll try to do my best with it!
[stderr] npm
[stderr] WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-launcher-a18e8b31/ios/ReactNative/EXDevLauncherRCTBridge.m'
[stderr] npm WARN tar
[stderr] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-launcher-a18e8b31/ios/Errors/EXDevLauncherRedBox.m'
[stderr] npm WARN tar
[stderr] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-launcher-a18e8b31/ios/Unsafe/RCTPackagerConnection+EXDevLauncherPackagerConnectionInterceptor.m'
[stderr] npm WARN tar
[stderr] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-launcher-a18e8b31/build/DevLauncher.js.map'
[stderr] npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-launcher-a18e8b31/build/DevLauncherErrorManager.js.map'
[stderr] npm WARN tar
[stderr] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-launcher-a18e8b31/build/DevLauncherErrorManager.web.js.map'
[stderr] npm WARN
[stderr] tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-launcher-a18e8b31/build/setUpErrorHandler.fx.js.map'
[stderr] npm WARN
[stderr] tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-launcher-a18e8b31/build/setUpErrorHandler.fx.web.js.map'
[stderr] npm WARN
[stderr] tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-launcher-a18e8b31/build/WebUnsupportedError.js.map'
[stderr] npm WARN tar
[stderr] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/devmenu/modules/DevMenuSettings.kt'
[stderr] npm
[stderr] WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-launcher-a18e8b31/android/src/debug/res'
[stderr] npm WARN tar
[stderr] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/devmenu/tests/DevMenuTestInterceptor.kt'
[stderr] npm WARN
[stderr] tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-launcher-a18e8b31/android/src'
[stderr] npm WARN tar
[stderr] ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/ios/Modules'
[stderr] npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/ios/Modules'
[stderr] npm WARN tar
[stderr] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/ios/DevMenuLoadingView.m'
[stderr] npm WARN tar
[stderr] ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/ios/Modules'
[stderr] npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/ios/Modules'
[stderr] npm WARN
[stderr] tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-launcher-a18e8b31/android/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi'
[stderr] npm WARN tar
[stderr] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/ios/DevMenuRCTBridge.m'
[stderr] npm WARN
[stderr] tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/vendored/react-native-reanimated/ios/Transitioning/DevMenuREAAllTransitions.m'
[stderr] npm WARN
[stderr] tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/vendored/react-native-reanimated/ios/Nodes/DevMenuREAAlwaysNode.m'
[stderr] npm WARN
[stderr] tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/vendored/react-native-reanimated/ios/Nodes/DevMenuREABezierNode.m'
[stderr] npm WARN
[stderr] tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/vendored/react-native-reanimated/ios/Nodes/DevMenuREABlockNode.m'
[stderr] npm WARN
[stderr] tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/vendored/react-native-reanimated/ios/Nodes/DevMenuREACallFuncNode.m'
[stderr] npm WARN tar
[stderr] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/vendored/react-native-reanimated/ios/Nodes/DevMenuREAClockNodes.m'
[stderr] npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/vendored/react-native-reanimated/ios/Nodes/DevMenuREAConcatNode.m'
[stderr] npm WARN tar
[stderr] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/vendored/react-native-reanimated/ios/Nodes/DevMenuREACondNode.m'
[stderr] npm WARN
[stderr] tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/vendored/react-native-reanimated/ios/Nodes/DevMenuREADebugNode.m'
[stderr] npm WARN
[stderr] tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/vendored/react-native-reanimated/ios/Nodes/DevMenuREAEventNode.m'
[stderr] npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/vendored/react-native-reanimated/ios/Nodes/DevMenuREAFunctionNode.m'
[stderr] npm WARN tar
[stderr] ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/react-native-b6181b95/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/common/network'
[stderr] npm WARN
[stderr] tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/vendored/react-native-reanimated/ios/Nodes/DevMenuREAJSCallNode.m'
[stderr] npm
[stderr] WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/vendored/react-native-reanimated/ios/DevMenuREAModule.m'
[stderr] npm WARN tar
[stderr] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-launcher-a18e8b31/android/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/dev_launcher_ic_refresh_white_36dp.png'
[stderr] npm
[stderr] WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/vendored/react-native-reanimated/ios/Nodes/DevMenuREANode.m'
[stderr] npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-launcher-a18e8b31/android/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/dev_launcher_ic_refresh_white_36dp.png'
[stderr] npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/vendored/react-native-reanimated/ios/DevMenuREANodesManager.m'
[stderr] npm WARN tar
[stderr] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/vendored/react-native-reanimated/ios/Nodes/DevMenuREAOperatorNode.m'
[stderr] npm WARN
[stderr] tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/vendored/react-native-reanimated/ios/Nodes/DevMenuREAParamNode.m'
[stderr] npm WARN
[stderr] tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/vendored/react-native-reanimated/ios/Nodes/DevMenuREAPropsNode.m'
[stderr] npm WARN
[stderr] tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/vendored/react-native-reanimated/ios/Nodes/DevMenuREASetNode.m'
[stderr] npm WARN
[stderr] tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/react-native-b6181b95/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/config'
[stderr] npm WARN
[stderr] tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/vendored/react-native-reanimated/ios/Nodes/DevMenuREAStyleNode.m'
[stderr] npm
[stderr] WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/vendored/react-native-reanimated/ios/Nodes/DevMenuREATransformNode.m'
[stderr] npm
[stderr] WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/react-native-b6181b95/ReactAndroid/src'
[stderr] npm
[stderr] WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/vendored/react-native-reanimated/ios/Transitioning/DevMenuREATransition.m'
[stderr] npm WARN
[stderr] tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/react-native-b6181b95/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/fabric/BUCK'
[stderr] npm
[stderr] WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/vendored/react-native-reanimated/ios/Transitioning/DevMenuREATransitionAnimation.m'
[stderr] npm
[stderr] WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-launcher-a18e8b31/ios/assets/bundle/assets/settings-filled-icon.png'
[stderr] npm
[stderr] WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/react-native-b6181b95/ReactAndroid/src'
[stderr] npm
[stderr] WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/vendored/react-native-reanimated/ios/Transitioning/DevMenuREATransitionManager.m'
[stderr] npm WARN
[stderr] tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/vendored/react-native-reanimated/ios/Transitioning/DevMenuREATransitionValues.m'
[stderr] npm
[stderr] WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-launcher-a18e8b31/ios/assets/bundle/assets/user-filled-icon.png'
[stderr] npm
[stderr] WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/react-native-b6181b95/ReactAndroid/src'
[stderr] npm WARN
[stderr] tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/vendored/react-native-reanimated/ios/Nodes/DevMenuREAValueNode.m'
[stderr] npm WARN tar
[stderr] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/vendored/react-native-gesture-handler/ios/Handlers/DevMenuRNFlingHandler.m'
[stderr] npm WARN
[stderr] tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/react-native-b6181b95/ReactAndroid/src'
[stderr] npm
[stderr] WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/vendored/react-native-gesture-handler/ios/Handlers/DevMenuRNForceTouchHandler.m'
[stderr] npm WARN
[stderr] tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/vendored/react-native-gesture-handler/ios/DevMenuRNGestureHandler.m'
[stderr] npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-launcher-a18e8b31/ios/Views'
[stderr] npm
[stderr] WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/react-native-b6181b95/ReactAndroid/src'
[stderr] npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/vendored/react-native-gesture-handler/ios/DevMenuRNGestureHandlerButton.m'
[stderr] npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/vendored/react-native-gesture-handler/ios/DevMenuRNGestureHandlerEvents.m'
[stderr] npm
[stderr] WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-launcher-a18e8b31/ios/ReactNative/EXDevLauncherBundleURLProviderInterceptor.swift'
[stderr] npm
[stderr] WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/react-native-b6181b95/ReactAndroid/src'
[stderr] npm WARN
[stderr] tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/vendored/react-native-gesture-handler/ios/DevMenuRNGestureHandlerManager.m'
[stderr] npm WARN tar
[stderr] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-launcher-a18e8b31/ios/Errors/EXDevLauncherErrorLogView.swift'
[stderr] npm WARN
[stderr] tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/root/workingdir/build/node_modules/.staging/expo-dev-menu-8a1c2d72/vendored/react-native-gesture-handler/ios/DevMenuRNGestureHandlerModule.m'
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? I've run into the same problem :(

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't however if you figure it out, don't forget me!

Comment: I've managed to get my build running this morning. It turned out to be a Node package that was being requested inside of `package.json` via `git://`. Switching out to `https://` for the requirement worked fine and the app built.

Comment: Great, some direction. Will see if I have the same case too.